# How to position awesome font on img and mimic hover properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I would like to put social media icons under the image beside the title of the photo. I.E facebook, twitter, Soundcloud and Instagram. I would like the social media icons to rotate with the image when the image is hovered over.

HTML

```
<div class="polaroid-images">          
    <a href="" title="Alex" ><img height="200" src="Alexandra.jpg" alt="Island" title="Alex" class=fishes /></a>
    <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.polaroid-images a
{
    background: white;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 15px 70px;
    padding: 10px 10px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: all .15s linear;
    z-index:0;
    position:relative;
}

.polaroid-images a, :after {
   color: #333;
   font-size: 20px;
   content: attr(title);
   position: relative;
   top:15px;
}

.polaroid-images img { 
   display: block; 
   width: inherit; 
}


.polaroid-images a, i:nth-child(3n) { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);  
    -moz-transform: rotate(-24deg); 
    transform: rotate(-24deg); 
}


.polaroid-images a:hover{
   -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
   -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); 
   -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
   transform: scale(1.2);
   z-index:10;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
   box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}

.polaroid-images i { 
   z-index: 11;
   padding 30px 25px 15px;
   margin-right: 10px 22px 30px ;
   position: absolute;
   top: 25%;  
   left: 25%;
   transform: translate(1%, 1%);    
   overflow: hidden; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the same transition on hover to the i. Like this:

```
.polaroid-images:hover i {
    -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
    -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
    transition: all .15s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the `a` and style it similarly to how you styled the `:after` that holds the image a `title`

```css
.polaroid-images a {
  background: white;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 15px 70px;
  padding: 10px 10px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transition: all .15s linear;
  -moz-transition: all .15s linear;
  transition: all .15s linear;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.polaroid-images a,
:after {
  color: #333;
  font-size: 20px;
  content: attr(title);
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.polaroid-images img {
  display: block;
  width: inherit;
}

.polaroid-images a,
i:nth-child(3n) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-24deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-24deg);
  transform: rotate(-24deg);
}

.polaroid-images a:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.polaroid-images i {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 1em;
  top: 15px;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: #3b5998;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="polaroid-images">
  <a href="" title="Alex"><img height="200" src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png" alt="Island" title="Alex" class=fishes /><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I then turn the FB icon into a link? When I try it pushes it out of the frame of the picture.